# Bootstrap carousel Not working on Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

### Site URL [Brandsroller.com](http://www.brandsroller.com/)

I have used bootstrap for my company site it is working fine till tomorrow but today its carousel stops working on Google chrome  its working fine on Firefox and IE.

My code

HTML

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="indexslider">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img alt="" src="img/home/seo_banner.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img alt="" src="img/home/design_development.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img alt="" src="img/home/responsive_web_design.png">                       
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#indexslider" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#indexslider" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
            </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {           
            $('.carousel').carousel();       
        });
```

Comment: how to fix?? console errors

Comment: it is not giving any and i cant find the problem in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see there's a problem in Chrome also, though if I put your HTML in a basic Bootstrap setup everything works well: http://bootply.com/67453 in Chrome.

Maybe update the jQuery you are calling and remove additional scripts and CSS and reinstall them one by one to identify the cause.