# Bootstrap Carousel won't work in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

For the past few weeks, I've been using the carousel bootstrap plugin without any problems. Just recently, it will not work. I've tried it on Firefox and it works fine. I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628276/bootstrap-carousel-not-working-on-google-chrome) and tried everything suggested and it still doesn't work. I've removed ALL the different scripts and css imports and try to ONLY get the carousel working and it still doesn't work.

Here is my carousel code:

```
        <!-- Ad Carousel -->
    <div id="ad_carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#ad_carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#ad_carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#ad_carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="images/ads/33.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/ads/55.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/ads/77.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#ad_carousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#ad_carousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Along with these:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap_3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap_3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap_3.1.1/css/theme.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/bootstrap_3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This plugin previously worked fine without any problems, but just today, without changing anything, no matter what I do, it won't work in Google Chrome. I don't know if it was a Chrome update that screwed something up, but I'm not sure what is going on.

I've researched online and could not find any similar problems other than one mentioned above.

What is making this plugin not work?
How can this be fixed to make this plugin work in Chrome again?

**EDIT**: Along with that, I'm getting no console errors.

**EDIT2**: So I've whittled it down to what I think the problem is. It's the image `src` links. I copy and pasted *isherwood*'s jsfiddle code of the carousel (in the comments) into my web page. For his images, he used links to some cat images. When I used his code, it worked fine, but once I tried to use some images from my server, it didn't work again. Using Chrome's web dev tools, I looked at the frame's resources. The images in the carousel aren't considered "images" (Or at least they aren't included in the images folder). They are in the "Others" folder. They are still a `.jpg` file, but Chrome sees them (from the resource and elements perspective) as a blank image with 0 width and 0 height (0px x 0px). When I double click on the image in the resources, Chrome opens the image in another window and it shows it fine.

This completely baffles me and I have no idea what is going on. I've tried many different things, but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/MY8Hr/

Comment: @isherwood i added an edit to the question

Answer (score 0):

May be should you disable all your Google Chrome Extensions ? They can cause bugs because they add their own javascript and styles in every html pages...

Is your console throws any errors?

Comment: I haven't installed or uninstalled any chrome extensions that would change something. And no console errors.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the bug, I copied your html and get the bootstrap 3.1.1, jquery min 2.1.1 and jquery.migrate min 1.2.1, and I tested it on Chrome 35.0.1916.114 and everything works fine ! The only difference I see is the '/bootstrap_3.1.1/css/theme.css' I don't have any file named theme.css in my bootstrap folder. Where does it come from?

Comment: Theme is a Bootstrap 2 carryover and only affects CSS.